# misunderstanding about the operator definition c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to understand why the operator (<) defined for this class insn't executed when called:

```
//File A.h (simplified class)
#ifndef __A__H
#define __A__H

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {

private:
    string _str;
    int _number;

public:
    A( string str="", int age=0): _str(str), _number(number){} //inline

    int operator < (const A &a1 ) const 
    {
        cout<<"Call of new operator <"<<endl;

        if ( _str == a1._str )
            return _number < a1._number; 
        return _str < a1._str; //here use of (<) associated to string 
     }

};
#endif

int main()
{
    A *obj1= new A("z",10);
    A *obj2= new A("b",0);
    int res=obj1<obj2; //res is equal to 1. There's no message              
                       // call of new operator"

    return 0;

}
```

What I've learned is that the redefinition of the operator permits its call. Any help ? thank you

Comment: if you just dont use `new` you will also solve your memory leak

Comment: `#define __A__H` The identifier that you define here is reserved for the implementation. The behaviour of your program is therefore undefined.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__A__H`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Also at global scope, names that begin with an underscore are reserved.  (Regardless if the next letter is uppercase, lowercase, or a digit, or another underscore.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj1` and `obj2` are `A*` not `A` so all you are doing is comparing pointer addresses. If you want to use `A::operator<` then you need to dereference your pointers

```
*obj1 < *obj2
```

Also why would you have your `operator<` return an `int`? It should return a `bool`.

Comment: Omg, what a bad mistake. I will never forget it. Thanks

Comment: Ok for bool return

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing pointers to `A`, not instances of `A` in this statement

```
int res=obj1<obj2;
```

You should compare like this:

```
int res=*obj1< *obj2;
```

You also have to delete the memory you have allocated at the end of the program.

```
delete obj1;
delete obj2;
```

Comment: Omg, what a bad mistake. I will never forget it. Thanks